# using javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop

I am trying to get the data from database and put it into js for loop

here is the php part:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$array[] = $row['value'];
```

here is the js part

```
var days=<?php echo json_encode($row['value']);?>;
    for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++){ 
    document.write("Number"+ days[i] +"<br>");
    }
```

When I try to `echo` the values, I can `echo` the array in the php part with no problem, but on the js part there is no error, just a blank page

---

OK whole scenario has changed when  viewed the page source

now my code is :

```
  rows = array();   
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db");
         $i=1;
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array[] = $row['value'];

        $i++;
        }


var days=<?php echo json_encode($array);?>;
            for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++){ 
            document.write("Number"+ days[i] +"<br>");
```

when I viewed the page source I can see the values

```
var days=["8","11","18"];
```

Now the next step is to implement it into js graph code

If I try the js code

```
 var days=<?php echo json_encode($array);?>;
            for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++){ 
            document.write("Number"+ days[i] +"<br>");
```

on a seperate page alone it works, but when I put the code in dataPoints

```
 dataPoints: [   

            {y: var days=<?php echo json_encode($array);?>;
            for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++){ 
            document.write(days[i] +"<br>");
            };, label: "test"},


        ]
```

I get blank page with no error. and still see the values when I view the page source . `var days=["8","11","18"];`

Comment: Can you share the generated html, say `view source` in the page and check it

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the output or knowing the data structures, but it seems like you meant to json_encode() the $array, not $row["value"]

Answer (score -1):

your page is blank because php return not string json

you can try:

```
var days= JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($row);?>");
    for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++){ 
    document.write("Number"+ days[i] +"<br>");
    }
```

Or:
php file:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
return json_encode($row);
```

js file:

```
$.get("phpfile.php",function(rs){
   var days = JSON.parse(rs);
   for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++){ 
      document.write("Number"+ days[i] +"<br>");
   }
});
```

Comment: `JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($row);?>");` does not make sense. If you echo a json encoded  data into javascript code, then this data is already in a form that is interpreted as JavaScript object.  Your code would result in something like `JSON.parse(["8","11","18"])`. The `JSON.parse` is not required in that case and would result an error because it expects a string.

Comment: If the JSON response is set up correctly on the server side then `JSON.parse(rs)` would not be required. If jQuery does not automatically parse the JSON data then the response type should be fixed sever side instead if using `JSON.parse(rs)`. Even if the response type cannot be fixed server side the `JSON.parse(rs)` should not be used, instead of that you should give the ajax request the info to interpret it as json.

Comment: hi @t.niese, 
JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($row);?>');
=> code return is like:
JSON.parse('{"name":"aaa","value":"bbb"}')